# How to print with Jupyter Notebook, the same way as it prints without print()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am having this code in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
sample_files = ["fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1"]
print_stuff = True
if print_stuff:
    print(sample_files)
sample_files
```

It produces this output:
[image]

I am not happy with the **format** of first one, produced by the `print(sample_files)`, and I want to make sure that it produces the same output, as the second, which goes without the `print()` function. Any ideas?

Comment: omit the `print`?

Comment: @depperm - it does not work, it does not output anything then.

Answer (score 0):

The word `display()` instead of `print()` does the magic:

```
sample_files = ["fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1","fooooooooooooooooooooo1"]
print_stuff = True
if print_stuff:
    display(sample_files)
sample_files
```

[image]